# struts2 file upload success message on same page using ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am uploading .csv file and redirecting on same page,I want to the display file upload successfully message on a same page.I don't want to send the request using ajax.I am new to struts framework I've gone through many file uploading tutorials but everyone is redirecting to a different page and displaying message there.

Comment: use ajax , get the response back on same page

Comment: There is no difference between redirecting to some page and same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set ActionError in your action(if file doesnt meet your criteria) using

```
     addActionError("file not uploaded something went wrong");
```

otherwise set action message

```
     addActionMessage("Upload successfully completed");
```

jsp page.

```
<body>
    <s:actionerror />
    <s:actionmessage />    

 <s:form action="uploadAction" >
    <s:file name="filename" /> 
    <s:submit />
 <s:form>
</body>
```

Comment: @Govi in which way this is better than the other answer provided ? Apart from the lack of the configuration and the check for the existence of the messages / errors (you may want to include actionMessages and actionErrors in div with special classes, for example to put red and green borders, and like this you can't), **It's also missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"`**... this would not even work :|

Answer (score 2):

After the upload (and in case of errors), dispatch the same page you come from:

Struts.xml

```xml
    <action name="uploadPage" class="foo.bar.UploadAction">
        <result>/upload.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/upload.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/upload.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="doUpload"   class="foo.bar.UploadAction" method="upload">
        <result>/upload.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/upload.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/upload.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

UploadAction

```java
    public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {       
        File   upload;
        String uploadFileName;
        String uploadContentType;       
        /* Getters and Setters for the above properties */

        public String execute() {
            return SUCCESS;
        }

        public String upload(){             
            try {
                getService().upload(upload,uploadFileName,uploadContentType);
                addActionMessage("Upload successfully completed");
                return SUCCESS;
            } catch (Exception e){
                addActionError("Error while uploading: " + e.getMessage());
                return ERROR;
            }
        }
    }
```

upload.jsp

```xml
<body>
    <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
        <s:actionerror />
    </s:if>
    <s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
        <s:actionmessage />    
    </s:if>

    <s:form action="doUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <s:file name="upload" />
        <s:submit />
    <s:form>
</body>
```

This is basic, then you may want to alter the URL or use Post Redirect Get or Tokens etc.. to prevent the user to resubmit the file when refreshing.